# product attribute not showing in cart price rule after enabling it magento 2.2.2

Tags: magento2, admin, admin-panel

[image]

**After enabling this and assigning it to products for cart rules, I am unable to see it from the drop down in cart rules below**

[image]

**This won't work for any existing or new attribute I create. I can't figure out what might be happening.**

**I have cleared the cache and reindexed am I am missing something? Has anyone else seen this?**

magento 2.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently clearing the cache from the backend and clearing from cmd line do two different things.

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

If you run into this run the above to clear cache and then try. :/